# How do I find a max of a column for each unique value in another column in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Say I have a dataset similar to this:
[image: Data]

My final product needs to be a row for each day of the Week with the Place that had the most Activities for that day. i.e. Mon Place A 56, Wed Place C 64, etc. I have tried using the Window function and am using max and groupie, but I am getting myself confused.

Answer (score 1):

For your purposes you need to write `window function`:

```
val df = Seq(
  ("Mon", "Place A", 10),
  ("Mon", "Place B", 42),
  ("Wed", "Place C", 41),
  ("Thurs", "Place D", 45),
  ("Fri", "Place E", 64),
  ("Fri", "Place A", 12),
  ("Wed", "Place F", 54),
  ("Wed", "Place A", 1)
).toDF("day", "place", "number")
df.show()
df.withColumn("orderedNumberForDay",
  row_number()
    .over(
      Window.orderBy(col("number").desc)
        .partitionBy("day")
    )
).filter(col("orderedNumberForDay") === lit(1))
 .select("day", "place", "number")
 .show()
/*                            
+-----+-------+------+        +-----+-------+------+
|  day|  place|number|        |  day|  place|number|
+-----+-------+------+        +-----+-------+------+
|  Mon|Place A|    10|        |  Mon|Place B|    42|
|  Mon|Place B|    42|  ===>> |  Wed|Place F|    54|
|  Wed|Place C|    41|        |  Fri|Place E|    64|
|Thurs|Place D|    45|        |Thurs|Place D|    45|
|  Fri|Place E|    64|        +-----+-------+------+
|  Fri|Place A|    12|   
|  Wed|Place F|    54|   
|  Wed|Place A|     1|   
+-----+-------+------+
*/
```

**Just a little explanation how it works**

Firstly you need to add column with `window function` result, here is:

```
df.withColumn("orderedNumberForDay",
  row_number()
    .over(
      Window.orderBy(col("number").desc)
      .partitionBy("day")
    )
)
```

`row_number()` - is counter of rows inside your `partition`. `Partition` is like group in `group by`. `partitionBy("day")` just grouping windows with same `day` column value. And finally we have to order this `window` by `number` in `desc` order, so there is `orderBy(col("number").desc` in our `window function`. `over` is like a bridge from `windows` to some useful computations inside `windows` and it's just bind `row_number` and `window function`.

After execution this stage we will have data:

```
+-----+-------+------+-------------------+
|  day|  place|number|orderedNumberForDay|
+-----+-------+------+-------------------+
|  Mon|Place B|    42|                  1|
|  Mon|Place A|    10|                  2|
|  Wed|Place F|    54|                  1|
|  Wed|Place C|    41|                  2|
|  Wed|Place A|     1|                  3|
|  Fri|Place E|    64|                  1|
|  Fri|Place A|    12|                  2|
|Thurs|Place D|    45|                  1|
+-----+-------+------+-------------------+
```

So, all we need is `filter` rows with `orderedNumberForDay` equals `1` - it will be with `max` `number` and select started columns: `day, place, number`. Final result will be:

```
+-----+-------+------+
|  day|  place|number|
+-----+-------+------+
|  Mon|Place B|    42|
|  Wed|Place F|    54|
|  Fri|Place E|    64|
|Thurs|Place D|    45|
+-----+-------+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Spark 3.0 introduced the aggregation function [max_by](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#max_by) that does exactly what you are looking for:

```scala
df.groupBy("day")
   .agg(expr("max_by(place, number)"), max('number))
   .show()
```

Result:

```
+-----+---------------------+-----------+
|  day|max_by(place, number)|max(number)|
+-----+---------------------+-----------+
|  Mon|              Place B|         42|
|  Wed|              Place F|         54|
|  Fri|              Place E|         64|
|Thurs|              Place D|         45|
+-----+---------------------+-----------+
```